# Sony smartwatch 2 check and change back light status programatically

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I am working on android app extension for sony smartwatch 2. I have some list and gallery view for that. Now i am able to open gallery view on list item click. I am using ActiveLowPower. When backlight is dim and user clicks on any of listview item it should first change backlight from dim to bright and then if backlight is bright it should call gallery view. How can i check and change smart watch backlight status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using SCREEN_STATE_AUTO for the low power mode to accomplish that.  If you set it to auto, then the backlight will automatically come on when the user touches the watchface.  Otherwise you can manually control the backlight state via SCREEN_STATE_ON or SCREEN_STATE_OFF.  To detect when the active low power mode state changes, you can check the ControlExtension.onActiveLowPowerModeChange() callback.

For more info see the Active Low Power Mode section here:
http://developer.sonymobile.com/reference/sony-addon-sdk/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveware/aef/control/Control#DisplayControl